# Scipy.generic_filter - window translation to 1D

Tags: python, scipy, ndimage

I am trying to use scipy.generic_filter to process an image. However, I need to further subset the window within the function I am applying. In another words I need to know the process (function) used to convert the 2D window to 1D array within the generic filter, so I can recreate the 2D array within the applied function in the right way. Does anybody know what function doe the scipy filter use to reshape the 2D to 1D?

Answer (score 0):

This is really late, but the data that gets passed to your filter function is a numpy array. You should just be able to reshape the data like normal

arr = arr.reshape((y, x))